# Right hand side of Einstein field equation

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, cosmological-constant, modified-gravity

Why can't the RHS of the [Einstein field equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_field_equations#Mathematical_form) take a form like $T_{\mu \nu}$ plus some coefficient multiplied with $g_{\mu \nu} T$?
It should also be covariantly conserved, I suppose? For example, if it is $T_{\mu \nu}+g_{\mu \nu}T/4$, the coefficient $\kappa$ that links the LHS and RHS of the field equation will be $\kappa=16\pi G/c^4$ by Newtonian limit.

Comment: The above version makes both the inverse of the coefficient in Einstein-Hilbert action and the coefficient in the field equation to be 16πG/c^4, which looks more elegant to me. Furthermore, the revised equation seems to be able to explain the elusive dark energy.

Comment: You do not satisfy the Bianchi identity. Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/658968/226902

Answer (score 7):

If I read you correctly, you are proposing to modify the Einstein equation as
$$
G_{\mu \nu} = \kappa (T_{\mu \nu} + \alpha g_{\mu \nu} T)
$$
where $\kappa$ and $\alpha$ are constants.  Because of the Bianchi identity $\nabla^\mu G_{\mu \nu} = 0$, and conservation of stress-energy $\nabla^\mu T_{\mu \nu} = 0$, taking the divergence of both sides yields
$$
0 = \nabla_\nu T.
$$

This is not, in general, satisfied by an arbitrary matter-energy source.  For example, for an arbitrary perfect-fluid source satisfying an equation of state $P = P(\rho)$, we have $T = -\rho + 3 P$ and so
$$
\nabla_\nu T = \left(-1 + 3 \frac{\partial P}{\partial \rho} \right) \nabla_\nu \rho
$$
which implies that the only way to satisfy $\nabla_\nu T = 0$ is for the density to be constant everywhere in spacetime.

Comment: Sorry to ask such an elementary question, but shouldn't the covariant derivative of the Lorentz invariant scalar T be conserved at zero? I thought it just like deferentiating a constant...

Comment: $T(x)$ is generically, not a constant. Why do you think it is?

Comment: @YuanLiu:  I've edited my answer with an illustration of why we shouldn't expect $T$ to be a constant.

Comment: +1 nice answer. @Yuan Liu, note that the "cosmological constant" is really a constant, not an arbitrary scalar field, and this is why you can introduce it in a way similar to what you propose (but not $T$). See also: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/726804/226902

Comment: @MichaelSeifert : Thanks for your kind explanation. May I further ask a fundamental question? Why, in the first place, should we believe so firmly in the conservation of energy? Can't it be violated very slightly such that we couldn't detect it to date? In fact, the radius of our observable universe is roughly 10^60 times of the Planck length, while the current density of our universe is roughly 10^(-120) times of the Planck density. I understand that such a relation (ρ∝a^(-2)) can be achieved if the pressure is negative, but it still suggests that energy may not be conserved, doesn't it?

Comment: @Quillo Thank you for your comment. Actually I am dubious about the conservation (both global and local) of energy in the first place. Please kindly refer to my reply to Michael, and let me know your thoughts on it as well. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @YuanLiu:  You should ask that as a new question (link back to this one for context.)  In general, the comments section on this site is for comments on existing answers, not for protracted discussions.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert. OK, let me try. I'm a beginner of this platform, not good at such manipulations Anyway, ρ∝a^(-2) due to negative pressure does not violate energy conservation (as long as it complies with the first law of thermodynamics) in your view, right?